# RotatingFileHandler and race conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, race-condition

I use [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) and I noticed that when several processes write to it at the same time, **each** of them rotates the file, so instead of 10MB `Foo.log.1` and a new `Foo.log`, I get a bunch of tiny `Foo.log.1`, `Foo.log.2`, `Foo.log.3` &c, and my 10MB of history is now completely gone.

Is this a known bug?

How do people deal with this?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. It seems that this package might solve it, but I haven't tried it yet: https://github.com/Preston-Landers/concurrent-log-handler

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [`WatchedFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#watchedfilehandler) and *rotate* the log file, if necessary, when the logger is created.